# What does the jquery statement "var collection = jQuery([1]);" mean?

Tags: jquery

On the page 109 of the book *"Learning JavaScript Design Patterns"*, there is a code sample which confused me.

```
jQuery.single = (function( o ){

    var collection = jQuery([1]);  // <-- i want to ask this line
    return function( element) {

         // give collection the element
         collection[0] = element;

         // return the collection
         return collection;
    }
})();
```

The use of the function is like this:

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
     var html = jQuery.single( this ).next().html();
     console.log( html );
});
```

**Update:**
Thanks for answering. I checked out the original code source from the author page [76 bytes for faster jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/76-bytes-for-faster-jquery/)

```
var collection = jQuery([1]); // Fill with 1 item, to make sure length === 1
```

Now I understand. I wish the author of the book  "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns" could add this comment too, when he cited this code sample.

Comment: I believe you are passing an array `[1]` to the function !

Comment: it would be easier if you post the related link

Comment: Take a look here http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/76-bytes-for-faster-jquery/

Comment: This looks like an extension of jQuery.

Comment: The question might be : "what is the point of having an array such as this one `$([1])` wether just this one : `[1]`"

Comment: It just returns a function that wraps an element in jQuery in a fancy way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jQuery([1])` is simply passing an array with one entry that contains the integer `1` into jQuery, that would return a wrapper to that array containing all jQuery prototype methods.

It later assigns the `element` argument variable into the very same array and then returns the entire jQuery instance.

From the looks of it, the whole function simply injects a **single** element into a *re-used* jQuery object and returns it.

It is presumed to speed things up and it actually does when you count millions of iterations over a second, but in my opinion this is a clear case of micro-optimization that can bite you in the ass during long debug hours. — *Perfection Kills*.

Comment: And how is that unused `o` parameter helping?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a predefined array into the jQuery() function.  let [1] mean "new array with only 1 element"

You can also write it like -

```
var collection = jQuery(new Array(1)); // or even $(new Array(1));
```

I think the reason they do this so there isn't any confusion on how many elements will be in the array.

Comment: Just a note: `new Array(1)` is not the same as `[1]`.